# In Java using the JTextPane and a HTMLDocument how do I make HTML bullet points which works similar to the way Microsoft Word does it?

Tags: java, html, wysiwyg

In Java using the JTextPane and a HTMLDocument how do I make HTML bullet points which works similar to the way Microsoft Word does it?
I have looked all over Stack Overflow to try to answer my question, but every answer which is similar is very buggy or does not create a new bullet point when pressing enter.

I have tried using

```
Action insertBulletAction = new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction ("Bullets", 
                                    "<ul><li> </li></ul>", HTML.Tag.P, HTML.Tag.UL);
```

But it only creates a bullet point and does not continue to create more when pressing enter.  How can I make it create more when creating a new line?

I know this is possible because it is done with SHEF and other wysiwyg/html editors.